# Variable ¨GET¨ with jquery, with URL friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, url

I have friendly url ex. `www.myweb.com/Mary` instead of `www.myweb.com/user?var=mary`

use this in the. htaccess

`RewriteRule ^ (\ w +) / $ user.php? Var = $ 1`

So far so good here.

But when I want to get the value in jquery, GET does not receive it.

```
(function($) {  
    $.get = function(key)   {  
        key = key.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[');  
        key = key.replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');  
        var pattern = "[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)";  
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern);  
        var url = unescape(window.location.href);  
        var results = regex.exec(url);  
        if (results === null) {  
            return null;  
        } else {  
            return results[1];  
        }  
    }  
})(jQuery);

var USER = $.get("var");
```

the value is null.

What's the problem?

Comment: URL handler should be implemented on the **Server-Side**. There is a very common pattern to handle this problem : Front Controller + MVC. Use this instead of implementing your own solution

Comment: The problem seems like `the value is null`.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @vol7ron No. Front Controller is responsible for instantiating MVC-triad based on `route-match`

Comment: @djay: ahh, that's what I think I call ApplicationController

Comment: @vol7ron There's no such thing as `ApplicationController`. Application class itself consists of dependencies like Front Controller itself and Service Locator. Have you see something like `$app->run()` in some frameworks? That's it

Comment: @djay: not to get too much into design pattern, but Rails has an ApplicationController, but I primarily use it as the gateway controller to the application.  It's the entry point from the server to handle and diagnose the query/command coming in.  So it would have the router, and route to the page or action controller.

Comment: You really shouldn't be overwriting `$.get`. That's an existing function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I solved this: var URL = window.location.pathname;

I catch this:  "/user"

and when I send the variable to php I remove the "/"

Thanks :)